# How custom Exception class automatically call the constructor of Exception Class?

Tags: php, exception, constructor

Custom exception class automatically call the constructor of the exception class without calling the parent constructor in custom exception constructor. As per my knowledge when we want to call the parent constructor on object of child class, then we have to write **parent::__construct()** in child class constructor. 
Please anybody tell me, how custom exception class automatically call the parent constructor of "Exception". 
Please see the below code,

```
    <?php
class customException extends Exception {

    /* function  __construct($email) {
        echo $email." custom exception constructor<br />";
    } */

    public function errorMessage() {
        //error message
        $errorMsg = 'Error on line '.$this->getLine().' in '.$this->getFile()
        .': <b>'.$this->getMessage().'</b> is not a valid E-Mail address';
        return $errorMsg;
    }
}

$email = "someoneexample.com";

try {
    //check if
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
        //throw exception if email is not valid
        throw new customException($email);
    } else {

        echo "Valid email";
    }
}

catch (customException $e) {
    //display custom message
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

OUTPUT IS:

> Error on line 41 in D:\wamp\www\exception.php: someoneexample.com is not a valid E-Mail address

**Update:**

```
  class ParentClass {

    function  __construct() {
        echo "This is parent class<br />";
    }
}

class Child extends ParentClass{

    function  __construct() {
        echo "This is child class<br />";
    }
}

$child = new Child();
```

**OUTPUT**
This is child class

Comment: It's already called automatically in your example. When you uncomment and override `__construct`, then you **have to** call it via `parent::`. That's just how it is. There's no further automatism.

Comment: mario: Please see my updated code, when I am not written the parent::__construct in child class constructor then in that case parent constructor will not be called and that above code parent constructor called autoimatically without writing any constructor in custom exception class.

Comment: Yes. And that's just how the language is designed. There is no implicit invocation of parent constructors when you declare `__construct` yourself.